# How can I run this function multiple times and plot each result?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following function and ggplot code. Essentially it runs through my database each time randomly removing one line per plot and calculating the frequency of each Category until there are only 5 lines per plot left. I then plot the calculated frequencies using ggplot and at the moment I am using a subset to only plot 4 IDs.

What I want to do is run the full function 5 different times and graph the results for each run on the same plot. The results should slightly differ since the function randomly removes lines. So the ggplot would have 5 lines per Category as opposed to the one line per category at the moment.

Initial Dataset (there are multiple plots, and 50 rows per plot:
[image]

Dataset after For Loop:

[image]

Code being used:

```
for ( i in 0:45){
if (i>0){
dat<- dat %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  sample_n(n() - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
}  
  
j<-dat %>%                               
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n), 
           total=50-i) 
if (i==0){
  tot_j=j
} else {
  tot_j=bind_rows(tot_j,j)
}
}

ggplot(subset(tot_j,Category %in% c("C" , "G","Z","S"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(total, freq, colour=Category)) +
  xlim(50,5)
```

Graph currently produced
[image: Plot with 4 categories]

I appreciate any help or advice! Still learning how to use r to its fullest extent!

Comment: Please do not provide datasets as images--provide us with a small but sufficient sample of the dataset as code so we have some data to work with. E.g., to answer your question, ~3-5 rows per plot for 2-3 plots and in 2 categories only will be sufficient. You can filter your dataset first, then use `dput()` to get the `structure()` of the data, which you can provide in the post as your sample data code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Your for loop is already looping your function multiple times. Do you want to add a loop to that loop? If you want to overlap multiple plots together, you can either row bind the multiple plot data together and add a column for the plot index of each dataset so that you can use it as a type of grouping variable for your `ggplot`, or add multiple `geom_line` to the `ggplot` such that the `data` in each `geom_line()` is the data for one of the plot datasets. I'd recommend the former.